# War deploying tomcat8

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, debian, jhipster, tomcat8

I have issue... I have spring-boot web application generated by jhipster. I need to deploy it with tomcat. Earlier I run it on virtual machine in home. Now I'm trying run it on OVH cloud. Everything is ok but when I type 'service tomcat8 start' and checking logs , I see that war is successfully deployed but it not run automatically after this operation. I was trying run it on windows and everything is okay. This same on virtual machine.. but on OVH always this same. 
I deploy original file . I have java8 and tomcat8 on server. Maybe I forgot about some configurations in tomcat? It's fresh after install . Can anybody help?

Comment: Any reason why you prefer the complex way (deploying in tomcat)  rather than simply running executable jar? Which version of  JHipster? You know that from version 3.7.0, JHipster switched from embedding Tomcat to Undertow, so did you modify your dependencies for Tomcat?

Comment: I solved my problem. For not known reason I had set java_home on different location . :) for anyone who Has that problem you must go into etc/default/tomcat8 and change java_home location on location from $java_home(type in linux bash)